# Playing a video in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am doing a project on Video steganography. I thought of playing the 2 video files in Java Swing to make the comparision of files easier. So i want to know if we can play a video in Swing? Please help me out!!

Answer (score 8):

You might want to take a look at the [Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html). A better alternative is probably using [JavaFX](http://javafx.com/). See [SimpleVideoPlayer](http://javafx.com/samples/SimpleVideoPlayer/) for an example.

Edit: You might also want to look at [vlcj](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/). It allows to embed a VLC player into a Swing java application.

Comment: Another one to look at is Xuggle.