# Adding a video or animation to the jframe in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, video, netbeans, background

I'm trying to make an application in java netbeans, I want to add a video or animations which will be the background of my Jframe.
please advise

Comment: *"'video/animation BG' please advise"*  Don't do that.  That's the best advice I can offer based on the available information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing a video in Java Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597185/playing-a-video-in-java-swing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered [JMF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html)? It's the standard way to play media with Java SE.